Transform a regular array into an array of objects inside a Mapping Data Flow in Azure Data Factory
In azure data factory, I have a column which is an array of strings like in this (image below):
costGroup = ["GH", "APT"]


Because I need to output in Json format later on, I need to transform it to an array of objects like this:
costGroup = [
                {"code": "GH"}, 
                {"code": "APT"}
            ]

I have been experimenting quite a bit with derived column transformation and with array functions but no success so far... any hint please?
Thanks in advance!

You can use Flatten and aggregate transformations to achieve your requirement.
First use Flatten transformation on your array.

It will flatten all items in the array like below.

Then use Aggregate transformation and group by all the remaining columns. In the aggregate section, use collect(@(code=code)) expression.


Result:


Hi Rakesh! thanks a lot, indeed, this is the approach I was following, however, I have more array columns which need the same transformation, so currently what I have is:
Flatten the first array column -> aggregate based on that column -> Flatten the second array column -> aggregate based on that
And so on
So I wanted to avoid so many steps and was trying to see if I could do the same with less steps, do you think there is a way? I thought about the map function in a derived column, something like:
map(costGroup, (index, value) => { 'code': value })
But that is not working

forgot to add before, I know that I can flatten and unroll by more than one column, however, this option is sequential, it first untrolls by one column, then unrolls again by the second column, and so on, so I end up with more rows than needed, this approach is not valid

You can use Flowlet which will work as a function to do the repetitive tasks. You need to use flatten and unroll by same column in each step.
